# Set UITableViewCell height proportional to image proportional

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image at 1x with the size of 320x130. I would like to set the `UItableViewCell` to always have the proportions of this image. How can i achieve this? i've tried below code, but seem to make the images very small?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {



    let ratio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 130
    let targetHeight = 130 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale


    return targetHeight / ratio
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` you should use the `tableView.bounds`, it's the same in your case, but if you change table view it will not work.

As for the ratio, it goes something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 130.0/320.0 * tableView.bounds.width
}
```

You get the ratio by dividing height with width and then you multiply it with the width of table view to get the desired height.